# jquery show popover if input's value is empty

Tags: jquery

Please help me to solve this problem. I have few inputs and when input is unfocused and input's value is empty i want to show popover with warning.

Here is what i've done. But its behavior is incorrect.
Also see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DAhU3/12/).

To reproduce my bug please follow these instructions:

- Focus on input #1 and then unfocuse it. Popover is showing and
  it's okay.
- Type something in input #1 and then unfocuse it. There is no
  popover and it's also okay
- Type something in input #2 and then unfocuse it, there is no
  popover also and it's okay.
- Focus again on input #1 and here is the popover again even input's
  value is not empty!

Where am i wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
        $(this).popover({
            title: 'Warning!',
            content: 'Value can not be empty',
            placement: 'bottom'
        }).popover('show');
    } else {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    }
})
```

Comment: use destroy instead of hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instand of using `popover('hide')` you should use `popover('destroy')`. Because hide just hides it, but it's still a popover. So it will appear on Mouseover / Focus.

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
        $(this).popover({
            title: 'Warning!',
            content: 'Value can not be empty',
            placement: 'bottom'
        }).popover('show');
    } else {
        $(this).popover('destroy');
    }
})
```

Try it as [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taqdhatb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Also, instead of checking `!$(this).val()`, you can have `$(this).val() == ''`

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == '' ) {
        $(this).popover({
            title: 'Warning!',
            content: 'Value can not be empty',
            placement: 'bottom'
        }).popover('show');
    } else {
        $(this).popover('destroy');
    }
})
```

Comment: i guess there is no difference "Also, instead of checking !$(this).val(), you can have $(this).val() == ''" and question was not about it. thaks

Comment: Yes I know the question was not about this if statements. But `!$(this).val()` is not the recommended way of doing it.

Comment: could you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

In [**bootstrap 4**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#popoverdispose), `.popover('destroy')` has been replaced with `.popover('dispose')`.

I realise this is an old question but this question is first on a google search about this topic, it would have saved me hours of head scratching if I knew destroy was changed.

Comment: you talk about bootstrap, but the answer was about jquery. Is this really an anwer to the question?