# How to show popover on the empty input on the submit?

Tags: javascript, webforms

NOTE: I googled it before asking a question in here.

I am checking the input before submitting the form using javascript, I want to show a popover on the top of the input if the value of input is empty for the purpose that the user might miss the empty required fields. I am using Javascript because there is no way I could show the popover in the code behind of webforms.

Now, I tried this solution I found here in stackoverflow [jquery show popover if input's value is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037201/jquery-show-popover-if-inputs-value-is-empty) to my code. and it does not do anything and no error on the console.

Here is my code:

```
                const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

                const requiredFields = Array.from(inputs).filter(input => input.required);

                var counter = 0;
                var isValid = false;

                for (let i = 0; i <= requiredFields.length - 1; i++) {
                    //skip if the field is disabled
                    if (!requiredFields[i].disabled) {
                        //check the field if required (the input field should be set to `required`)
                        if (requiredFields[i].required) {
                            //check if the value is not null
                            if (requiredFields[i].value === '') {

                                //Show popover 
                                requiredFields[i].popover({
                                    title: 'Warning!',
                                    content: 'Value can not be empty',
                                    placement: 'bottom'
                                }).popover('show');
   
                                isValid = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    counter += 1;
                }
```

How can I possibly trigger the popover when the input value is empty? Can someone lead me to correct way to solve this?

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried adding a `debugger` statement in the code? You can use that to step through your code and see what's happening.

Comment: Whut, Someone already help me answer this question. So this is already closed. Where did that go.

Comment: They must have deleted their answer. Good to hear you got it figured out though. :)

Comment: What the f. so you can delete the accepted answer now huh. shame.